# How do I add a number that I type in a textbox to an array, and how can I orde ir from the largest to the smallest?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I would like to know how can I add or type a number in a textbox, then this number gets saved, then add other numbers, and save them so at the end I can order them from larger to smaller and viceversa.

I got one textbox (where I type the numbers), one button (add button, that adds the typed number to the textbox2), another textbox2(where the numbers are being added simultaneously, so you can check them). There is a textbox3 (where the numbers must appear ordered from larger to smaller) and a textbox4 (where the numbers must appear ordered from smaller to larger).

Can someone help me?

Comment: [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), [List<T> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), [List.OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but it works. Try it.:)

```
    //index count
    int index=0;

    //array declaration
    string [] numbers=new string[10];

    //method displaying array's content
    string arrayDisplay() {
        string str="";
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!(numbers[i]== "") )
            {
                str += numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text;
        index++;
        if (numbers.Length >=index )
        {
            numbers[index] = textBox1.Text;
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        //Regular sort and display
        Array.Sort(numbers);
        textBox3.Text = arrayDisplay();

        //Reverse sort and display
        Array.Reverse(numbers);
        textBox4.Text = arrayDisplay();

    }
```